# Deferred requests in scrapy

Tags: scrapy, twisted

I would like to repeatedly scrape the same URLs with different delays. After researching the issue it seemed that the appropriate solution was to use something like

```
nextreq = scrapy.Request(url, dont_filter=True)
d = defer.Deferred()
delay = 1
reactor.callLater(delay, d.callback, nextreq)
yield d
```

in parse.

However, I have been unable to make this work. I am getting the error message 
`ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'Deferred'`

I am not familiar with twisted so I hope I am just missing something obvious

Is there a better way of achieving my goal that doesn't fight the framework so much?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found an answer in [an old PR](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/254)

```
def parse():
        req = scrapy.Request(...)
        delay = 0
        reactor.callLater(delay, self.crawler.engine.schedule, request=req, spider=self)
```

However, the spider can exit due to being idle too early. Based on the outdated middleware https://github.com/ArturGaspar/scrapy-delayed-requests, this can be remedied with

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exceptions import DontCloseSpider

class ImmortalSpiderMiddleware(object):

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_idle, signal=signals.spider_idle)
        return s

    @classmethod
    def spider_idle(cls, spider):
        raise DontCloseSpider()
```

The final option, updating the middleware by ArturGaspar, led to:

```
from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary

from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exceptions import DontCloseSpider
from twisted.internet import reactor

class DelayedRequestsMiddleware(object):
    requests = WeakKeyDictionary()

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        ext = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_idle, signal=signals.spider_idle)
        return ext

    @classmethod
    def spider_idle(cls, spider):
        if cls.requests.get(spider):
            spider.log("delayed requests pending, not closing spider")
            raise DontCloseSpider()

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        delay = request.meta.pop('delay_request', None)
        if delay:
            self.requests.setdefault(spider, 0)
            self.requests[spider] += 1
            reactor.callLater(delay, self.schedule_request, request.copy(),
                              spider)
            raise IgnoreRequest()

    def schedule_request(self, request, spider):
        spider.crawler.engine.schedule(request, spider)
        self.requests[spider] -= 1
```

And can be used in parse like:

```
yield Request(..., meta={'delay_request': 5})
```

Comment: This can be implemented in a more simple way with Scrapy 1.0. Check https://github.com/ArturGaspar/scrapy-delayed-requests again for the new more simple version.